# Does closure under concatenation imply closure under Kleene and positive closures?

Tags: computer-science, formal-languages

Are both [Kleene closure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kleene_star)(0 or more replication) and positive closure (1 or more replication) special cases of concatenation? Does the number of operands matter here: infinitely countable, vs finite?

Does closure under concatenation imply closure under Kleene and positive closures?

Do  the definitions of AFLs and full AFLs from Ullman's *Introduction to Automata Theory, Languages and Computation* have redundancy?

> Define a class of languages to be an abstract family of languages
> (AFL) if it is a trio and also closed under union, **concatenation**, and
> **positive closure**.
>
> Call a class of languages a full AFL if it is a full trio and closed
> under union, **concatenation**, and **Kleene closure**.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Closure under concatenation does not imply closure under $L \to L^*$ (Kleene closure) and $L \to L^+$ (positive closure): just take the class of finite languages as a counterexample.

Comment: Thanks. Could you elaborate " the class of finite languages"? What is it?

Comment: A *class of languages* associates with each finite alphabet $A$ a set of languages on $A^*$. Here I consider, for each alphabet $A$, the set of finite languages on $A^*$.

Comment: Is "the class of finite languages" not the power set of $A^*$? Are finite languages those with finite numbers of strings?

Comment: A language is just a subset of $A^*$. Thus yes, a finite language is a finite subset of $A^*$, that is a language containing a finite number of words (or strings, if you prefer). The power set of $A^*$ is larger, since it also contains infinite languages.